# Is this asbestos pipe insulation

Tags: insulation, asbestos, renovation, demolition

I have been doing work around a house I purchased. Never even thought pipe insulation would have or could have asbestos. My home was built in 1976 and is on Long Island NY (not sure if this helps.) I fixed a pipe leak and carelessly ripped off this insulation not even thinking. Just started gutting another room and found this. Could it contain asbestos being that it’s from a home built in 1976? I know to be sure it would need testing, but is there a high chance this is?[image]Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It does not look like typical fiberglass. The era is right. Testing and reasonable care is certainly advisable, as is a reminder that most "effects of asbestos exposure" are from chronic exposure (folks that worked with the stuff) not whatever tiny bit you may have been exposed to in ripping one or two pipes open before going: *Hmm, this doesn't look like what I was expecting.*

The only way to know for sure is to have it tested at a lab (if you get exorbitant prices and scare tactics, keep shopping for a reasonable lab.)

Comment: « Folks that worked with the stuff » - heard stories that pipe fitters used to bunch the asbestos insultion into « snowballs » and throw them at each other...

Comment: I'm glad to see people saying that illness from asbestos comes from chronic, long term exposure in manufacturing or installation settings, rather than it just being present, but contained.  There was so much hysteria about it (probably driven by lawyers) earlier that you'd it was plutonium.